# Multiply two column of the same dataframe

Tags: dataframe, nan, multiplication

I really don't understand why I obtain NaN value after multipied two column of the same dataframe:

I have 2 column, 1 float and 1 int.

I wrote:

```
df['total'] = df_prt.Quantity * df_prt.Price
```

This is the result:

```
600000    * 110.319199 = Nan
-600000   * 1.106900   = Nan
9000032.4 * 30000      = Nan
43797     * 19.603200  = 3.161641e+06
```

Why I obtain Nan?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is the correct results:

```
600000    * 110.319199 = Nan
-600000   * 1.106900   = Nan
90000     * 32.430000      = Nan
43797     * 19.603200  = 3.161641e+06
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if both values are numeric.

```
df_prt = pd.DataFrame([
    [600000, 110.319199],
    [-600000, 1.106900],
    [9000032.4, 30000],
    [43797, 19.603200],
], columns=['Quantity', 'Price'])

df_prt['total'] = df_prt.Quantity * df_prt.Price
```

This results in the expected behaviour.
So I would assume some of your data has the wrong type (e.g. *string* instead of float).

`df_prt.dtypes` and `df.dtypes` might give you some information on which types might be mismatched.